# Передача данных с помощью Netty

Tags: java, json, netty

Версия netty: 4.1.25.Final

При отправке json, взамен одного, отправляется целых два.

Действия.

Client -> Отправил json...

Server -> Обработал, отправил два json. (Вот на этой стадии начинаются непонятные вещи. Сервер отправил два json:

- Первый: {"pID":1,"spID":null,"d":1,"uID":"c53c0a8e-5993-4243-b062-259d766979f8"}
- Второй: {"pID":54,"spID":1,"d":"","uID":""})

Client -> Читает первый и второй.. и тут он надумал мне дать такой ответ: {"pID":1,"spID":null,"d":1,"uID":"c53c0a8e-5993-4243-b062-259d766979f8"}{"pID":54,"spID":1,"d":"","uID":""}

Клиент должен был прочитать первый json обьект, а потом уже второй, а не два сразу.

Answer (score 0):

Не ясна суть проблемы. Вы не можете на клиенте прочитать ответ от сервера? Сервер отдает строку? Какой библиотекой на стороне сервера формируете ответ? Кто клиент? Браузер? Читаете javascript-ом ответ? Если так, то можно передавать ответ в виде массива (списка)

```
[
    {"pID":1,"spID":null,"d":1,"uID":"c53c0a8e-5993-4243-b062-259d766979f8"}, 
    {"pID":54,"spID":1,"d":"","uID":""}
]
```

Такой ответ можно прочитать через `JSON.parse()` и получить массив объектов, и обработать как надо.

Comment: Сервер использует стандартный метод для отправки строки channel.writeAndFlush(String);

В тоже время сервер отправляет те два json обьекта о которых идёт речь. Они должны были читаться отдельно, но клиент получил ответ в виде одной строки, в которой находятся два json Обьекта.

Comment: @MartelsMafia, а вот тот самый `String`, который Вы передаете в `writeAndFlush`, Вы как формируете?

Comment: Для конвертации обьекта в Json используется библиотека Gson. Ещё такая информация появилась, с первым соединением всё проходит гладко, без той ошибки о которой я говорил, а после второго соединения начинается бред. Если у вас есть такая возможность хотелось бы как-то в другой обстановке с вами пообщаться.